# Why does heroku say no module found on profile read

Tags: django, heroku

I am tryning to deploy a app. But I am getting the following error.I think this might have something to do with wsgi file path location.

I am getting this error:

```html
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980813+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980815+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980817+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980818+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980820+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980823+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980824+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980826+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980829+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980830+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980832+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980834+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980835+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-12-22T13:31:42.980841+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'EIIIFeedback'
```

My pr0ject structure is:
[image]

my Procfile is :

```
web: gunicorn EIIIFeedback.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

Your directory have name EIIIFeedBack, but gunicorn searching for a EIIIFeedback, which means you need to fix gunicorn's comand.